# Delete Azure automation job

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, powershell-workflow

I know `Stop-AzureAutomationJob` will stop the job. But how can you delete the job altogether? ie. I don't want it to show up in the list of jobs for that runbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported. Jobs cannot be deleted.